# receiving incomplete data in $_POST after posting through post

Tags: php, ajax, xml, post

> I am posting xml through ajax to my php page following is the client side cod here i am creating my xml and posting to php page , I have tried doing setting in php.ini file but it is not working for me

```
 var issuedetails = JSON.stringify(issues);
        passdata =  "<passdata><fdata>" +
                    "<req_date>" + req_date + "</req_date>" +
                    "<req_time>" + req_time + "</req_time>" +
                    "<customer_number>" + customer_number + "</customer_number>" +
                    "<customer_name>" + customer_name + "</customer_name>" +
                    "<customer_address>" + customer_address + "</customer_address>" +   
                    "<customer_locality>" + customer_locality + "</customer_locality>" +
                    "<customer_city>" + customer_city + "</customer_city>" +
                    "<customer_email>" + customer_email + "</customer_email>" +
                    "<channel>" + channel + "</channel>" +
                    "<serviceType>" + serviceType + "</serviceType>" +
                    "<vehicle_type>" + vehicle_type + "</vehicle_type>" +
                    "<vehicle_number>" + vehicle_number + "</vehicle_number>" +
                    "<vehicle_make>" + vehicle_make + "</vehicle_make>" +
                    "<vehicle_model>" + vehicle_model + "</vehicle_model>" +
                    "<vehicle_variant>" + vehicle_variant + "</vehicle_variant>" +
                    "<vehicle_segment>" + vehicle_segment + "</vehicle_segment>" +
                    "<fuel>" + fuel + "</fuel>" +
                    "<category>" + category + "</category>" +
                    "<manf_year>" + manf_year + "</manf_year>" +
                    "<kmreading>" + kmreading + "</kmreading>" +
                    "<lastservice>" + lastservice + "</lastservice>" +
                    "<issues>" + issuedetails + "</issues>" +                                         
                    "<action>" + "submit_new_customer_booking" + "</action>" +
                    "</fdata></passdata>";
    }
    Jprocessingstart();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: "model_booking_table.php",
            data: "data=" + encodeURIComponent(passdata),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                   // alert("fail");
                   alert("some error occured->" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
            }

    }).done(function (msg) {
        alert("Booking done successfully!");
        Jprocessingend();
        location.reload();
//      BookingConfirmationCommunication();
    });
```

> following data i am posting to php

```
 <passdata><fdata><req_date>2017-09-26</req_date><req_time>10:30</req_time><customer_number>9673******</customer_number><customer_name>rahul</customer_name><customer_address>CST no 235 & 239, Sonai Apt, Office no 3, Upper grnd flr, near lokmanya vachnalay</customer_address><customer_locality>Sadashiv Peth-411030</customer_locality><customer_city>Pune</customer_city><customer_email>******************@gmail.com</customer_email><channel>Direct</channel><serviceType>Dry</serviceType><vehicle_type>TW</vehicle_type><vehicle_number></vehicle_number><vehicle_make>TVS</vehicle_make><vehicle_model>Jupiter</vehicle_model><vehicle_variant>Select</vehicle_variant><vehicle_segment></vehicle_segment><fuel></fuel><category></category><manf_year></manf_year><kmreading></kmreading><lastservice></lastservice><issues>[{"issue":"Meter not working","diagnosis":"Speedo Meter cable broke, Speedo meter gear broke, Speedo meter unit damage","solution":"1) Speedometer Cable: Check / Replace 2) Speedometer Gear: Check / Replace 3) Assembly: Replace","parts":"Speedometer Cable Speedometer Gear Speedometer Assly","comments":"","estimate":""}]</issues><action>submit_new_customer_booking</action></fdata></passdata>
```

> following data i am receiving on my php

```
<passdata><fdata><req_date>2017-09-26</req_date><req_time>10:30</
 req_time><customer_number>9673******</customer_number><customer_name>rahul</
 customer_name><customer_address>CST no 235 & 239, Sonai Apt, Office no 3, Upper grnd flr, near lokmanya 
 vachnalay</customer_address><customer_locality>Sadashiv Peth-411030</
 customer_locality><customer_city>Pune</customer_city><customer_email>******************@gmail.com</
 customer_email><channel>Direct</channel><serviceType>Dry</serviceType><vehicle_type>TW</
 vehicle_type><vehicle_number></vehicle_number><vehicle_make>TVS</
 vehicle_make><vehicle_model>Jupiter</vehicle_model><vehicle_variant>Select</
 vehicle_variant><vehicle_segment></vehicle_segment><fuel></fuel><category></category><manf_year></
 manf_year><kmreading></kmreading><lastservice></lastservice><issues>[{"issue":"Meter not 
 working","diagnosis":"Speedo Meter cable broke, Speedo meter gear broke, Speedo meter unit 
 damage","solution":"1) Speedometer Cable: Check / Replace 2) Speedometer Gear: Check / Replace 3) Assemb
```

> the data after Assemb is missing when i receive , i am receiving post data using following code

```
$preceivedata = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: What is value of `post_max_size` and does it exceeds your XML size?

Comment: @Justinas post_max_size is 8M, can you tell me how to count XML size if you know

Comment: You say "this is what i am posting". To clarify, is it the content of the `passdata` before you POST the data, or is it what you see in the debug tool of your browser? (If you're unsure how to use the debug tool of your browser, just press F12 - that is how it is activated in at least Chrome and Firefox, probably other browsers as well.)

Comment: @ninad Simply copy all data to notepad and save it. Check file size

Comment: "this is what i am posting"  it is content of passdata before posting , and i am posting passdata in ajax by doing  data: "data=" + encodeURIComponent(passdata),

Comment: size of the data i am posting is 1.17kb

Comment: @Justinas do you have any idea or can you  suggest me different solution for doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue was  tag in my xml contains '&' character 'CST no 235 & 239, Sonai Apt, Office no 3, Upper grnd flr, near lokmanya 
>    vachnalay' ,
>   which was making it invalid xml , i tried some solutions like encodeURIComponent(),escape() functions of java script but it did not work , what work is 'replace'  function of javascript ,
>   Before putting value in  tag i did

### **customer_address = customer_address.replace(/&/g , 'and')**

> it solved my issue